# Internal Subset DTD referencing External DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have a number of XML documents that use the same main Document Type Definition (mrinitialman.dtd).  Certain elements get a small tweak depending on which page they are in: for example, the SetPage element, which is defined so:

```
<!ELEMENT SetPage ((SetImgInf|SetRecInf)?, SetPageName,SetPageDesc?,%credits;)>
            
            <!ELEMENT SetPageName (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT SetPageDesc (#PCDATA)>
```

SetImgInf and SetRecInf are not defined in this document type definition; they are defined in the doctype subsets of the files in which those elements are needed.

For example, recordings.xml has this for a Document Type Declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE MainPage SYSTEM "../Site_Data/XML_Etc/mrinitialman.dtd"[
    <!ELEMENT SetRecInf EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST SetRecInf recfile CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
```

I define SetRecInf there because it is the *only* file to use that element.

Two files, however, use SetImgInf: art_gallery.xml and photo_gallery.xml; their doctypes are so:

```
<!DOCTYPE MainPage SYSTEM "../Site_Data/XML_Etc/mrinitialman.dtd" [
    <!ELEMENT SetImgInf EMPTY>
        <!ATTLIST SetImgInf
            imgkeywords CDATA   #IMPLIED
            imgfile     NMTOKEN #REQUIRED
            imgformat (jpg|gif|png|tff|bmp) #IMPLIED 
            thumbformat (jpg|gif|png|tff|bmp) #IMPLIED
        >

]>
```

Is it possible to put that bit into its own DTD, and thus have both art_gallery.xml and photo_gallery.xml to effectively reference two separate external document type definitions?

Answer (score 0):

In XML (and SGML), you can put any markup declaration into an external entity and then reference that external entity. In your example, you'd put

```
<!ELEMENT SetImgInf EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST SetImgInf
        imgkeywords CDATA   #IMPLIED
        imgfile     NMTOKEN #REQUIRED
        imgformat (jpg|gif|png|tff|bmp) #IMPLIED 
        thumbformat (jpg|gif|png|tff|bmp) #IMPLIED
    >
```

into `setimginf.dtd` (say), and then change the place(s) where that fragment is used by a parameter entity declaration and subsequent reference:

```
<!ENTITY % setimginf SYSTEM "setimginf.dtd">
%setimginf;
```

Technically, using an external subset such as in your example

```
<!DOCTYPE MainPage SYSTEM
  "../Site_Data/XML_Etc/mrinitialman.dtd" [
  <!ELEMENT SetImgInf EMPTY>
]>
```

is equivalent to

```
<!DOCTYPE MainPage [
  <!ELEMENT SetImgInf EMPTY>
  <!ENTITY % mrinitialman SYSTEM
    "../Site_Data/XML_Etc/mrinitialman.dtd">
  %mrinitialman;
]>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it didn't seem to work.  Could that be because I'm processing my XML through PHP, and PHP itself isn't co-operating?